# Use of MOVs without fuse?

Tags: protection, fuses, surge-protection, mov

I understand the MOVs become almost short-circuit when input voltage across them exceed a threshold.

[image]

But how does this protect the circuit behind the MOVs? Suppose the input power supply voltage increases due to a surge in the diagram above. Even if the dynamic resistance of the MOV drops to near zero, the circuit to be protected will still have the surge voltage applied across it so the protected circuit will still see an overload voltage.

My hypothesis till now as to how MOVs protect is based on following:

1. Either the underlying assumption is that the input supply has finite internal impedance and once the MOV start drawing large current, most of the surge voltage gets dropped across the internal impedence
2. Or the assumption is that a fuse is always placed in series with MOVs and the high current drawn by the MOV causes the fuse to blow, hence protecting the circuit.

Which is the correct hypothesis?

Comment: It depends on the power supply. The grid cannot be affected by an MOV

Answer (score 1):

There should be preceded by *something* fusible. They usually fail short when they have absorbed enough spikes to wear out.

But yes, the assumption would be that the source has a reasonably high impedance for the MOV to work. They don’t usually blow a fuse in normal operation, they simply absorb some of the spike energy and turn it into heat.

Even short circuit current at the end of a mains cord, for example, is not all that high. And spikes that originate from inductive switching (motors, solenoids, transformers) have a maximum source current equal to the current that was flowing through the inductance. It’s the latter kind of spikes that they are useful in suppressing, however note that they have quite a high voltage across them when performing that task, so your circuit may have to withstand several times normal voltages or more without dying.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the protected circuit will see an overvoltage for sure.
But the question when talking about surges is always **energy** that is voltage, current and surge duration.

As an example, most of the circuits can withstand HBM ESD strike up to 2 kV. It is a very high voltage but can be managed by the internal ESD diodes of the circuit.
ESDs are high voltage surges but quite low current and really short (in the range of ns). So they are low energy surges.

In your case, you are not talking about ESD but surges occurring on the power mains: much longer than ESD and higher current so much more energetic.

The job of the MOV or the TVS will be to sink as much current as possible in case of surge without increasing too much the voltage thanks to a very low dynamic resistance.
The remaining current and clamping voltage going to the protected circuit should be low enough to be managed by the internal protection of the circuit to be protected by the MOV.

For power mains inputs, we consider IEC 61000-4-5 also called 8/20 µs exponential current waveform.
We have issued a 10 min video explaining the different surges and how protection devices do the job. Here is the link:

[Protecting circuits against surges](https://st-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/EP_introduction-Protecting-circuits-against-surges_0320_JR_NEW.mp4)

**Now concerning fuse:**
Most of these protection devices fail in short-circuit (first) in case of surges much higher than expected. So placing a fuse between the power mains and the MOV or the TVS would avoid short-circuiting the power mains which is always a bad idea.

Why do I say MOV or TVS fail first in short-circuit ?
Because if there is no overcurrent protection (like a fuse), then unlimited current will flow through the MOV or TVS and finally will blow it up and end with an open circuit. But usually nobody wants to reach this uncontrolled point!

***Edit to answer questions in the comments section:***

1. To simplify, the IEC 61000-4-5 surge generator acts more or less like a capacitor discharge. You charge the capacitor up to a given voltage, let’s say 2kV and then you discharge it in the DUT.

The generator is calibrated in short-circuit and must generate an exponential waveform 8/20 µs and in open-circuit and must generate an exponential voltage waveform of 1.2/50 µs.
But once a DUT is connected to the generator, the waveforms can de modified as we are no longer in the case of open or short-circuit.

2. As the surge generator has a serial resistance (Rs), the clamping voltage at the TVS can be maintained low as soon as the dynamic resistance of the TVS is low enough.
   To select the right TVS you have to know which level of the maximum voltage is acceptable for the circuit to be protected (you can take a the AMR as first approach) and then select the IEC 61000-4-5 class of surges you want to pass.
   This application note details how to calculate surge current and clamping voltage:

[TVS clamping protection mode](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an316-tvs-clamping-protection-mode-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Concerning the surge resistance, it can be 2, 12 ohm in the IEC 61000-4-5 for power lines.
Let me give another link describing this standard. You will find the classes and which resistance to consider. You will find more details as well on what I briefly explained above.

[IEC 61000-4-5 standard overview](https://emcfastpass.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/surge_overview.pdf)

I guess IEC 61000-4-5 is the right standard to consider in your case as you are referring to power input.

Comment: Two questions:
1) Is surge modeled as a voltage source or a current source?
2) If the surge is modeled as an ideal voltage source with zero impedance, then wouldn't the current drawn by DUT be V/R_dut, hence independent of whether the MOV/TVS is present or not (and power will always be V*V/R_dut)? The video you provided also mentions 2ohm input impedence. So is that assumption always true (non-trivial input impedance is required for MOVs to work)?

Comment: I have answered you questions by editing the initial post. I hope it clarifies